# Best way to join two tables of different servers and different databases in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to join two tables of different servers and databases. Below is my code for using OpenQuery but I'm not sure what I did wrong:

Code:

```
--Fetch data from cccTrn01.dbo.account INTO TempTable
SELECT * 
INTO #TmpTable 
FROM OPENQUERY([CCCTRN01SQL\CCCTRN01],
               'SELECT * FROM [CCCTRN01SQL\CCCTRN01].[dbo].[account]')
```

Error:

> OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "CCCTRN01SQL\CCCTRN01" returned message "Deferred prepare could not be completed.
>
> Msg 8180, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> Statement(s) could not be prepared.
>
> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> Invalid object name 'CCCTRN01SQL\CCCTRN01.dbo.account'

Comment: When the statement is remoted to the server, you do not then need to specify the server name again. `[CCCTRN01SQL\CCCTRN01].[dbo].[account]` looks for `dbo.account` in a *database* named `CCCTRN01SQL\CCCTRN01`, which is probably not what you want. The database name is just `cccTrn01` (if your comment is accurate).

Comment: Yes, the syntax for OPENQUERY() should be `OPENQUERY([LinkedServer], 'SELECT * FROM [Database].[Schema].[Table]')`

Comment: Do you have linked server configured? Otherwise the query won't work as far as I know... another approach would be to use SSIS for this kind of task. YOu can define a data flow ehich features a Join / Lookup / whatever to joind the data...

Comment: so, should my line of code look like: --Fetch data from cccTrn01.dbo.account INTO TempTable
Select * INTO #TmpTable From OpenQuery([CCCTRN01SQL\CCCTRN01],'Select* FROM [dbo].[account]') ? -- I got the same error after editing

Comment: You need to specify the database in the query. Assume the linked server connection is not defaulting to the correct database on the remote server. It's probably looking in master.

Comment: Ok Thanks Bacon Bits